# Exercise in Jacobson's $Basic\ Algebra\ I$, Chapter 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, modules

Well, I even don't understand the problem.

> Let $R$ be a ring and let $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ be a base for $R^{(n)}$. If I define:
>   $$
> f_j=\sum_{j'=1}^n a_{jj'}e_{j'}
> $$
>   for all $j \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$, then I have to prove the following:
>   $$
> (f_1,\ldots,f_m)\ \text{is a base for $R^{(m)}$} \Longleftrightarrow \ \exists B\in\mathcal{M}_{n \times m}(R)\ \text{such that}\ AB=1_m,\ BA=1_n,
> $$
>   where $1_m$ is the  unit matrix in $\mathcal{M}_m(R)$ (analogous with $1_n$).

What I don't understand is how the $f_j$'s could be a base of $R^{(m)}$ if they're in $R^{(n)}$?

Comment: It probably means that the $f_j$'s form a basis of a submodule of $R^{(n)}$ that is isomorphic to $R^{(m)}$.

Comment: Is $R$ assumed to be commutative?

Comment: I think you would learn enough about what the problem wanted you to learn by just taking $m=n.$

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: No, $R$ i'snt commutative.

Comment: @Jim : Thx, I don't get  how to proceed in that case, but I'm going to think about it.

Comment: @RagibZaman , thx for that suggest.

Comment: I think that is simply a typo in the question and should read "...$(f_1,\dotsc,f_m)$ is a base for $R^{(n)}$". And, IMO, it would have been better to state the exercise something like this: "Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ a left $R$-module and $(e_1,\dotsc,e_n)$ a basis of $M$. ... Then $(f_1,\dotsc,f_m)$ is a basis of $M$ iff... " Of course, if $M$ has such bases, then $M \cong R^{(n)} \cong R^{(m)}$. For noncommutative rings, this is possible even for $m\neq n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take @ladisch suggestion and show the following:

> Let $R$ be a ring and let $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ be a basis for $R^{(n)}$. Define
>   $f_j=\sum_{j'=1}^n a_{jj'}e_{j'}$ for $j \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $A=(a_{jj'})$. Prove the following:
>   $$(f_1,\ldots,f_m)\ \text{is a basis for $R^{(n)}$} \Longleftrightarrow \ \exists B\in\mathcal{M}_{n \times m}(R)\ \text{such that}\ AB=I_m,\ BA=I_n.$$

If $(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$ is a basis for $R^{(n)}$, then there exist $b_{ij}\in R$ such that $e_i=\sum_{j=1}^mb_{ij}f_j$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. Then $e_i=\sum_{j=1}^mb_{ij}\sum_{j'=1}^n a_{jj'}e_{j'}=\sum_{j'=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^m b_{ij}a_{jj'})e_{j'}$ and thus $\sum_{j=1}^m b_{ij}a_{jj'}=\delta_{ij'}$. Set $B=(b_{ij})$. Then $BA=I_n$. Analogously one can prove $AB=I_m$.

Conversely, since $(f_1,\ldots,f_m)^T=A(e_1,\ldots,e_n)^T$ (by $^T$ we denote the transpose) and $BA=I_n$ we get (by multiplying with $B$ to the left) $B(f_1,\ldots,f_m)^T=(e_1,\ldots,e_n)^T$, and therefore $(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$ is a system of generators for $R^{(n)}$. Now suppose that $\sum_{j=1}^ma_jf_j=0$ with $a_j\in R$. Using that $(f_1,\ldots,f_m)^T=A(e_1,\ldots,e_n)^T$ and $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ are linearly independent we get $(a_1,\dots,a_m)A=0$. Since $AB=I_m$ we get (by multiplying with $B$ to the right) that $(a_1,\dots,a_m)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know if this was the right place to put it, sorry if that's not the case. I could solve the problem with this change:

> $$
> \text{Exists $\eta$ isomorphism from $R^{(n)}$ into $R^{(m)}$ such that $\{\eta(f_1),\ldots,\eta(f_m)\}$ is a basis for $R^{(m)}$} \Longleftrightarrow \ \exists B\in\mathcal{M}_{n \times m}(R)\ \text{such that}\ AB=1_m,\ BA=1_n
> $$